# Add rules to pattern at least capital letter, lowercase letter, number, symbol, no repeated characters and 8 characters exact length

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a RegEx to match a string with the following criterion:

1. The first character must be a letter.
2. At least one number.
3. At least one capital letter.
4. At least one lowercase letter.
5. At least one symbol `(can be any of these: $, @, #, *, /, &, !, ¿, ?, ¡, +, -, %, (, ), =)`
6. No repeated characters (example: 22, www, 5555)
7. The string must be 8 characters exact length.

Examples:

```
W23@r#k8
Xa$4=6/w
Pe4*5v?-
M2%e5(7f
Qsd!Y7a
```

I development this pattern but it is not enough:

```
^([a-zA-Z]){1}([A-Za-z0-9]){7}$
```

This pattern validate 1 and 7 point.

Thanks!

Comment: The last `Qsd!Y7a` should not be matched, right? See https://regex101.com/r/zA6txG/1.

Comment: Sorry, is Qsd!Y7a2

Comment: Thanks! buddy @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-])[a-zA-Z](?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-]{7}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA6txG/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(.)\1)` - there cannot be identical consecutive chars
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - there must be at least 1 uppercase ASCII letter somewhere to the right in the string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - there must be at least 1 lowercase ASCII letter somewhere to the right in the string
- `(?=.*[$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-])` - there must be at least one char from the character class somewhere to the right in the string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - the first char is an ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - there must be at least one digit somewhere to the right in the string
- `[A-Za-z0-9$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-]{7}`  - 7 chars, letter, digits, special chars from the char class
- `$` -  end of string.

Note that if you allow *any* chars in the string, replace `[A-Za-z0-9$@#*\/&!¿?¡+%()=-]{7}` with `.{7}`.